# How to do dynamic expression in ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects (`list: any[]`) that I use in an `*ngFor` expression. Is it possible to display one of the properties from the object when I know the property name at runtime?

I am creating a component, called `ListComponent` that displays a list of items. The parent component called `ParentComponent`, will pass in the array of objects and the property that it wants the `ListComponent` to display in the list. 
Here is what I have so far in the `ListComponent`:

```
<div>
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Instead of `{{item.name}}`, is it possible to make the `.name` part dynamic and use the property passed in by `ParentComponent`?

Comment: Can you give an example what you want to do? I do not understand the .name part dynamic. If your item.name change, it will update the ListComponent too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a 'dynamicKey' variable in your .ts that changes and access it like below. You could also optionally provide a default or empty string for the case it is undefined.

```
<div>
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item[dynamicKey] || ''}}</div>
</div>
```

Another approach may be to create an array from the object based on your dynamic key, to reduce logic in the templates.

```
dynamicArray = itemList.map(item => item[dynamicKey])
<div>
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of dynamicArray">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great thank you. i think i will work. i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code. here name is variable which can be dynamic from component.

```
<div>
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item[name]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Component**

```
  @Input()  parentKey
  itemList=[{key:'State',value:'state'},
  {key:'Severity',value:'severity'},
  {key:'Priority',value:'priority'},
  {key:'Category',value:'categorization'},{key:'Owner',value:'owner'}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of itemList">{{item[parentKey]}}</div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fakfmp?file=src/app/app.component.html